# Enter data in EditText and respond without pressing enter

Tags: android

I have an editText with a listener.

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

            // Perform action on key press
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Now I want to use the data entered in the textBox by the user in my program without the user pressing enter. (If I remove `(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)` then the program hangs for some reason).

What should I do to identify that the user has entered some character in the textbox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want to implement functionality like whenever user enter any character you want to check , if this is the case then there is a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) class for you. In which you can override its 3 methods: `afterTextChanged`, `beforeTextChanged` and `onTextChanged`.

```
mPasswordLength = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_length);
mPasswordLength.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }
});
```