# Getting edit text value without pressing any key in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

My requirement is as follows: I need to get the data from multiple text
boxes (`EditText`) and I need to calculate and show it in the another
`EditText`. How it is possible? As I mentioned there is no button to
press automatically it needs to appear in the total box.

I [referred this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242661/enter-data-in-edittext-and-respond-without-pressing-enter), but after the loop I'm not getting the value I
declared the variable globally but also not getting the value of the
text box.

```
EditText et1, et2, etTot;
int x, y, tot;
et1 = (EditText) findViewbyId(R.id.edittext1);
et2 = (EditText) findViewbyId(R.id.edittext2);
etTot = (EditText) findViewbyId(R.id.edittextTot);

et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                              int count) {
        x = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString().trim());
        System.out
                .println("AMOUNT IS " + et1.getText().toString());

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});

//same as for et2......

tot = x + y;

etTot.setText(tot.toString());
```

Comment: please post your code, shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @ Dheeresh Singh not getting the values out side the block to adding that x and y values.

Comment: why needed out side ? see answer...... even outside how you 'll get event to update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//global variable
EditText et1,et2,etTot;
int x,y,tot;

// in 0nCreat()
et1 = (EditText)findViewbyId(R.id.edittext1);
et2 = (EditText)findViewbyId(R.id.edittext2);
etTot = (EditText)findViewbyId(R.id.edittextTot);


et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
    int count) {
        <Activity_NAME>.this.updateValue();
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
    int after) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
    });

et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
    int count) {
        <Activity_NAME>.this.updateValue();

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
    int after) {

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
    });


//in class       
private void updateValue(){
    String str1 = et1.getText().toString();
    String str2 = et2.getText().toString();

    if(null!=str1 && str1.lenght()>0 && null!=str2 && str2.lenght()>0)                  
    {
        try{
            x= Integer.parseInt(str1.trim());
            y= Integer.parseInt(str1.trim());

            tot = x + y; 
            if(null!=etTot)
                etTot.setText(tot+"");
            else 
                Toast.makeText(this,"etTot is null ",Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
            }catch (NumberFormatExcption nfe){}
        }

    }
```

Comment: not getting the tot when i'm entering the values in text box app is crashing

Comment: when entering values  its throwing following exceptions

Comment: 06-06 14:31:17.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1563): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 14:31:17.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1563): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-06 14:31:17.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):  at in.pack.operations.expenses.ReportExpenses.updateValue(ReportExpenses.java:532)

06-06 14:31:17.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):  at in.pack.operations.expenses.ReportExpenses.access$7(ReportExpenses.java:524)
06-06 14:31:17.651: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):  at in.pack.operations.expenses.ReportExpenses$7.onTextChanged(ReportExpenses.java:238)06-06

Comment: NullPointerException very much predictable . :)

Comment: can you tell me which is line 532 ReportExpenses.java file

Comment: etTot.setText(tot.toString()); this is the line of that 532.

Comment: ok so either etTot is not initiated in onCreate or id R.id.edittextTot does not exists in current ecreen layout........

Comment: id was given in layout and it is also initiated in the oncreate().in the layout also it was created

Comment: if(null!=etTot) in this before caliculation how ever etTot is null

Comment: if(null!=etTot) in this before caliculation ? not got ?

Comment: tot = x+y;if(null!=etTot)etTot.setText(tot+"");else                        Toast.makeText(this,"etTot is null ",Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();} in this etTot is null so it will goes to else it's ok.Have u observed exception it is thowing null pointer exception it was another problem na...

Comment: yes... that's why i am saying etTot is null ..... why it is null ? I already told to probable reasons...... this is the only problem here...

Comment: As you said all the things are right but when i'm entering the values in the text boxes it is taking fine but when it comes to if condition it returning false so it is going into the else block here it is printing toast.when entering value in the text boxes.

Comment: i have not given it as you observe i don't have that much points to  give you -1.

Comment: etTot is null must be due to either etTot is not initiated in onCreate or id R.id.edittextTot does not exists in current screen ... so please provide the complete Activity and XMl of this to get solution...

Comment: Thanks till now code is not updated now it got updated even though i have updated it now i have restarted eclipse multiple times so now the code got updated and got the result .Thanks for support.Great cooperation.I'm Accepting your Answer.Once Again THANKS ALLOT.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class that implements TextWatcher and override following methods:

```
    @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable editable) {
            // check if user has filled some value in all editTexts
        }


        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence string,
                final int start, final int count, final int after) {
        }


        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence string, final int start,
                final int before, final int count) {
        }
```

Use above code for last `editText`, and check if all `editTexts` contains some value i.e. they are not having value as "" or `null`. if yes then retrieve all the text from these `editTexts` and calculate what you want.